# Remove software entirely from system

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, uninstall

> What way can I remove a software entirely from my Windows OS?

Most Games and Programs leave a lot of trash after uninstall from Program Files and this really makes a problem since I often have to search for this trash and remove it personally. I never know what files a software installed into the system and where to search for them after uninstall but unfortunately some files are left there unneeded and take up space and litter the system.

3rd party software can be used if it's not too much of a problem. However, better an in-system non-3rd-party solution if such exists.

Comment: Are you willing to use 3rd party programs to do so? I know of one, but I guess I should ask before posting an answer. (Also I'm new-ish here so I don't even know if I can recommend 3rd party programs.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Revo Uninstaller](https://www.revouninstaller.com) to do this. After selecting which program to uninstall you will be able to see all files and registry keys it leaves behind and choose to keep/delete them.

Comment: I've seen your comment under the question. You may find this helpful: [*How do I recommend software in my answers?*](https://meta.superuser.com/a/5330/432690)

Comment: What about posts into system files like **host** and other intrusions into different system files? Will it remove those lines too? Will it remove game save files and game cache? Will it remove software temp and cache files?

Comment: It deletes the files like cache and temp files. I'm not sure about the files it's written into. I never thought about that.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thanks. I'll check it out.